# Embedded Graph Database

Tags: database, graph

I'd like to embed a [open source] graph database in my application. I looked a lot and finalized on orientdb embedded version. We have a prototype running but now have an additional restriction for application to not use java libraries. Does anyone have a suggestion of a C++ (maybe) embedded graph db?
Thanks!

Comment: What did you settle on?